# Error with trained LBP cascade in OpenCV 2.4 on OSX lion

Tags: macos, opencv

I am trying to train cascade based on [this](http://gigadom.wordpress.com/2011/10/07/opencv-haartraining-and-all-that-jazz/) post and [official](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) documentation.

My gear is:

- Mac OSX Lion
- OpenCV 2.4.0

So, I have created negative images, positive samples and trained cascade, all without errors, however when I try to test created cascade using **opencv_performace** I got following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)) in cvRead, file /Users/tekielskib/Projects/Wprawki/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 4863
terminate called throwing an exceptionAbort trap: 6
```

Same thing happens when I create Haar cascade and save it using *-baseFormatSave* switch.

I am kind of stumped and don't know haw to nail down the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://code.opencv.org/issues/1694

There are two versions of xml format for cascades in OpenCV and the new format of cascades is not supported by the opencv_performance. But LBP cascades are only exist in newer format.

Comment: Should have checked it before... Thanks!